# Most efficient way to read specific information from xml data returned from a wcf service

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have data being returned (in the form of a string) from a wcf service that resembles what you can see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc uname="xxxxxxx" pword="xxxxxxxx" doctype="RET" status="ACK" errorcode="0">
  <salesnote sntype="B" action="INSERT" salescontractref="" saledate="20121114" auctionid="" logbooknums="" landingdecnums="" vesselname="Titanic" vesselpln="ABC123" vesselmasterowner="Michael Mouse" landingdate1="20121112" landingdate2="" landingdate3="" countryoflanding="GBR" landingportcode="GBHTG" status="ACK" errorcode="E302 [Sales line(s)]" id="25005">
    <salesline speciescode="NEP" faoareacode="27" zonecode="" disposalcode="" freshnesscode="U" sizecode="3" presentationcode="HEA" statecode="FRE" numberoffish="" weightkgs="52.00" value="15.00" currencycode="GBP" withdrawndestinationcode="" buyerreg="" salescontractref="" status="ACK" errorcode="E302 [Invalid species cross reference codes used]" />
  </salesnote>
</abc>
```

In reality there will be many more 'salesnote' elements with their corresponding 'salesline' elements and they should be error free!!

I am currently submitting data to wcf service and collecting the return information (an example of which is above) to a rich text box.  From this return I wish to extract the information contained in the last attribute ("id") of each 'salesnote' element.  In this case it would just be 25005 but there could be twenty of thirty to collect.  I need to collect them in order so that I can then carry out further processing with those id's.

I have considered using an xml reader for this, but that would probably require that I save the result out to a file first before reading it in and then working on it. I have also been wondering if there would be a way to write a linq query against the contents of the text box given that it is properly formatted xml.

I suspect that there is a really efficient way to do this  that turns out to be quite simple so to that end I thought I would ask if any of you have some bright ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim abc As XElement = XElement.Parse(yourStringOrYourControlContent)
For Each id As String in abc.<salesnote>.@id
  Console.WriteLine(id)
Next
```

should do.